# Best Drupal module for facebook Opengraph and Linked in

Tags: facebook-graph-api, drupal-modules, facebook-opengraph, linkedin-api, facebook-oauth

i wanna create alumni association website using drupal.so user(student,alumni,staff) can sign up/login using facebook/linked in.their details should be fetch from their social network profile.so which module is suitable for this criteria.Thanks in advance.suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me share my experience with Drupal and Facebook and related modules.

Out of all the modules in there, I liked [drupal for facebook](http://drupalforfacebook.org) the most. It is very simple to configure, works nice. The drawback is it is a bit heavy and it still does not support some modern facebook stuff (like opengraph, custom actions etc). But no doubt it is the best module regarding to Facebook, I have ever used.

Now comes the problem of using Drupal modules with Facebook. All of them I found uses PHP-sdk and is slow and not modern stuff friendly (reloads the page once the user is logged in etc.).

Now you have two choices,
1. if you are into programming or can hire one for this small task, create a small module (one javascript file and one php file, that's it) and be done with it. I have done that quite nicely, though it was my first drupal module. If you want I (and a lot of people) can help you with the coding part.
2. If you don't want that, go with drupal for facebook.

Comment: good effort.now i plan to use fboauth.its really easy to customize and easily can mapping your facebook details with user fieds.i have working getting friends working history and education history functionality ..